# PutLifecycleHook operation: Unable to publish test message to notification target (FIFO)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, aws-auto-scaling

There are many documents that explain how to resolve this error. Checked many of them and tried . However following them is not resolving this issue for me.

Error I get is

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutLifecycleHook operation: Unable to publish test message to notification target arn:aws:sqs:xxxxx:XXXXX:kubeeventsqueue.fifo using IAM role arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/kubeautoscaling. Please check your target and role configuration and try to put lifecycle hook again.

The command I am using is:

> aws autoscaling put-lifecycle-hook --lifecycle-hook-name terminate --auto-scaling-group-name mygroupname --lifecycle-transition autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING --role-arn arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/kubeautoscaling --notification-target-arn arn:aws:sqs:xxxxx:XXXXXXX:kubeeventsqueue.fifo

Note that I have replaced XXXXX for the actual ids above.

The role concerned (`arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/kubeautoscaling`) is having trust relationship with autoscaling.amazonaws.com. It is also having "AutoScalingNotificationAccessRole" policy attached to it.

While testing, I have also tried adding a permission of "Allow everybody" for All SQS Actions (SQS:*). (Removed it after testing though).

I have also tried to first create SQS queue and then configure `--notification-target-arn`, without any success.

Any help on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are using an Amazon SQS FIFO (first-in-first-out) queue.

From [Configuring Notifications for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks - Receive Notification Using Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/configuring-lifecycle-hook-notifications.html#sqs-notifications):

> FIFO queues are not compatible with lifecycle hooks.

I don't know whether this is the cause of your current error, but it would prohibit your desired configuration from working.

Comment: That was indeed the case ! Thanks a ton to you sir. I dont know how i missed this part, i should have at least tried non FIFO queue, my bad. Now error is gone and i can see notification target registered for the lifecycle hook. The error message given by tool was also misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, FIFO queues are definitely not supported by LifeCycleHooks. I Wasted a lot of time dorking with permissions and queue configuration only to finally find that FIFO is not supported. It would be nice if this were much more prominent in the documentation because 1) it's way not obvious or intuitive and 2) the error message received suggests it's permissions or something. How about explicitly stating "FIFO Queues are not supported" instead of "Failed to send test message..." RIDICULOUS!